# Django model validation not raising Exception on full_clean()

Tags: python, django

I have a `Model` and `ModelForm` with custom validator (which only allows "H" or "A" in the CharField):

```
def home_away_valid(value):
    return value == 'H' or value == 'A'


class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=180)
    home = models.CharField(max_length=2, validators=[home_away_valid], default='H', db_index=True)


class TeamForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['home', 'name']
```

However when I run full_clean() with another value (not H or A) it doesn't not raise a validation exception:

```
try:
    team = TeamForm({
        'name': 'Test Team',
        'home': 'S'
    })
    team.full_clean()
    new_team = team.save()
    print(new_team.id)
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e)
```

Why does this not raise an Exception? (I have tried doing the `full_clean()` on both the `ModelForm` and `Model`, neither raises an Exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A validator should raise a `ValidationError` in case the condition is *not* met, not return `True` or `False`, so:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def home_away_valid(value):
    if value not in ('H', 'A'):
        raise ValidationError('Must be home or away')
```

You also might want to use `'H'` and `'A'` as choices, this will render the form with a `ChoiceField`, making it less likely to make mistakes:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    HOME_AWAY = (
        ('H', 'Home'),
        ('A', 'Away')
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=180)
    home = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=HOME_AWAY, validators=[home_away_valid], default='H', db_index=True)
```

Comment: I dont support the answer, from django shell, full_clean() raises a validation error when called on a presaved instance, but in a view it does not work. So I will likely downvote the wrong answer you gave above,

Comment: @optimus: it makes no sense that it raises a `ValidationError` in the shell, but not in the view. The origin of the call is nearly always irrelevant. Technically speaking you *can* inspect the traceback and see if it originates from the view, but that is not the case in Django and would also be (very) bad design :).

Comment: Exactly my point, but in this case imagine , it is a unique_field an you decided to test clean the model instance before saving , your answer may be in context but does not really fix the cause of ValidationError not being raised on full_clean(), that is my point. Especialy if to us bulk_create etc

Comment: @optimus: normally `full_clean` will *raise* a `ValidationError`, both in the shell and in the view. The reason is does not do that for `bulk_create` is because it will nog call `.full_clean`, `.clean`, or even `.save`. If you want to do that, you will need to loop over the list and call `.clean`/`.full_clean` before calling the `.bulk_create` on the list of items. But Django deliberately has no signals, save handlers, validation on `.bulk_create` since that would likely lose any benefit the `.bulk_create` offers. If you work with `.bulk_create`, you need to know what you are doing.

Comment: @optimus: normally `.bulk_create` is *not* used if you want to validate user input: a `ModelForm` will eventually call the field validators, and therefore thus invalidate if you use anything else but `H` or `A` as `home` field.

Comment: Dont mind this side question, it is apart from what we talking about? Here , Is it better to deploy django to say aws ec2 with or without docker in production?